# Can't group by with AS MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables containing flight data and I'm trying to return the type of plane that has been used the most

So far I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT Planes.type, COUNT(Planes.type) AS Number FROM Flights
JOIN Planes ON Flights.idPlane = Planes.idPlanes
GROUP BY Planes.Type
```

It returns the following:

```
type     Number
737      1
747      4
767      1
777      2
787      2
A320     1
A330     1
```

Now, I'm only trying to see the highest number with the corresponding type. What I tried was `GROUP BY Number DESC`, but it tells me Error code 1056 can't GROUP BY it. If it would work I'd use LIMIT to only show me the top record as that would be the highest.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: Use `ORDER BY` to sort.

Comment: If you just want the type with the highest Number value, why wouldn't you use ``ORDER BY Number DESC`` and then select the first record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This One...

```
SELECT Planes.type, COUNT(*) AS Number
FROM Flights JOIN Planes ON 
    Flights.idPlane = Planes.idPlanes
GROUP BY Planes.Type 
ORDER BY Number DESC;
```

it will retrieve the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT Planes.type, COUNT(Planes.type) AS Number
FROM Flights
    JOIN Planes ON Flights.idPlane = Planes.idPlanes
GROUP BY Planes.Type
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `ORDER BY 2` is prone to errors! What if you include a column before the `COUNT(Planes.type)`.. Well this query is small so you may catch `ORDER BY 2` intime but what if you had a query that is over a A4 page long?